# Powershell script to log out users without specific process

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that will log out users which don't have specific process running in their session.

I guess the workflow should look like:
Get usernames of all the users logged in, get list of all the processes runnning on the workstation, check if X process is running for Y user, if not, then log user Y out.

So far i managed to create object with all the users currently logged in:

`((quser) -replace '^>', '') -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv`

And list of all the processes running with usernames:

`get-process -IncludeUserName`

I believe foreach with if inside should do the job, but I can't quite get my head around it. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

edit:

```
$process = get-process -IncludeUserName|Where-Object{
($_.ProcessName -Like "processIneed1*") -or
($_.ProcessName -Like "processIneed2*") -or
($_.ProcessName -Like "processIneed") -or
($_.ProcessName -like 'processIneed3*') -and
($_.username -notlike '*userIwantToSkip1*') -and
($_.username -notlike '*userIwantToSkip2*')
}
$users = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -Property UserName -NE 'administrator'
$ActiveUsers = $users.username

foreach ($ProcUser in $process.username){

    foreach ($ActiveUser in $ActiveUsers){

        if ($ProcUser -like "*$ActiveUser*"){
        $ActiveUsers = $ActiveUsers -notlike "*$ActiveUser*"
        }
    }
}
```

in `$activeusers` we are left with inactive users.
I will most likely change username to session ID and check it this way.
Next step will be logging off disconnected users.

Comment: [1] add the name of the process in  question to your `Get-Process` call. [2] save that to a $Var. [3] iterate thru your `quser` list with a `foreach` loop. [4] check to see if the current quser item matches a name in the  process list. [5] do the appropriate thing for each case. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey as for selecting the process i need ```get-process -IncludeUserName | Where ($_.ProcessName -eq 'rdpshell')``` is not working, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the `Get-Process` cmdlet has a `-Name` parameter ... that is what i was referring to. [*grin*] something like this >>> `Get-Process -Name 'thunderbird' -IncludeUserName` <<<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$process = get-process -IncludeUserName|Where-Object{
($_.ProcessName -Like "processIneed1*") -or
($_.ProcessName -Like "processIneed2*") -or
($_.ProcessName -Like "processIneed") -or
($_.ProcessName -like 'processIneed3*') -and
($_.username -notlike '*userIwantToSkip1*') -and
($_.username -notlike '*userIwantToSkip2*')
}
$users = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -Property UserName -NE 'administrator'
$ActiveUsers = $users.username

foreach ($ProcUser in $process.username){

    foreach ($ActiveUser in $ActiveUsers){

        if ($ProcUser -like "*$ActiveUser*"){
        $ActiveUsers = $ActiveUsers -notlike "*$ActiveUser*"
        }
    }
}

foreach ($inactiveusers in $ActiveUsers){
logoff $inactiveuser
}
```